# Override standard page with VF page and save which has dynamic picklist in it

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, standardcontroller

I have VF page to override standard contact "new" button page, In that VF page i have Project field which will get the picklist value(project name) dynamically when i insert one project(custom object) record, I'm facing problem when i'm saving record, that is even if i select one project name from pick list  it is not saving, can't able to save the record.

Here is my VF page and controller.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Account_ext" tabStyle="account" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="Person Contact Edit">
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" />



   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <Apex:pageBlockSection >

     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
<apex:outputpanel >
    <apex:outputfield value="{!Contact.Salutation}" />
    &nbsp;
    <apex:outputfield value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
</apex:outputpanel>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>   

        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


        <Apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Lead_Source__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Budget__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_check__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Flat_Type__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Locality_Preference__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Location__c}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Name__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Potential_Name__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Property_Type_Preference__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Type_Of_Purchase__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Lead_Source__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_City__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_Country__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_State_Province__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_Street__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_Zip_Postal_Code__c}"/>  
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Opportunities__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Project__c}"/>

      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
       <apex:outputLabel >Project</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!prj_Name}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!prj}" />
                    </apex:selectList>   
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
    </Apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class Account_ext {

    public Account_ext(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public string prj;
    public string prj_name{get;set;}

    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    public List<selectOption> getprj() {
        for(project__c acc : [select Id,name from project__c])
        {
            options.add(new selectOption(acc.name,acc.name));
        }
        return options;
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `prj_name` is just a controller property and these are not automatically persisted.

You need to bind your `apex:selectList` to an SObject field, in this case presumably a custom field added to Contact (e.g. `Contact.Prj_Name__c`), so that when the standard controller `save` is invoked the value is automatically saved as part of the `Contact` SObject.